# remove un-wanted characters in email using preg-replace

Tags: php, preg-replace

I want to sanitize the email a#$%#$@b@#$#$2344324.com to a@b.com . 
I tried and failed 
   echo filter_var("a#$%#$@b@#$#$2344324.com", FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL); //result: a#$%#$@b@#$#$2344324.com

I need to trim special characters in a email(sanitize to remove special characters). I used below code but I was unsuccessful.

```
$string = preg_replace("/^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/", "", "a#$%#$@b@#$#$2344324.com");

echo $string;//result: a@b.com -- unwanted characters trimmed here.
```

Comment: try and explaining what you are trying to do, how you are trying to do it, what you expect to see, and why what you saw didn't meet those expectations. there are real experts on this site, although usually their expertise are in software, not clairvoyance

Comment: there is no sense in such an action

Comment: What’s the point/rule of turning `a#$%#$@b@#$#$2344324.com` into `a@b.com`?

Comment: That's a validation regex, not a character filter. You've copied two unrelated examples together, which is why it doesn't work. Btw, there is `filter_var()` and VALIDATE_EMAIL and FILTER_EMAIL or whatever it's called.

Comment: Col. Shrapnel, you mean to say that a#$%#$@b@#$#$2344324.com is valid instead of a@b.com?

Answer (score 1):

There is already a RFC-based solution here: http://fightingforalostcause.net/misc/2006/compare-email-regex.php

```
function is_valid_email_address($email){

        $qtext = '[^\\x0d\\x22\\x5c\\x80-\\xff]';

        $dtext = '[^\\x0d\\x5b-\\x5d\\x80-\\xff]';

        $atom = '[^\\x00-\\x20\\x22\\x28\\x29\\x2c\\x2e\\x3a-\\x3c'.
            '\\x3e\\x40\\x5b-\\x5d\\x7f-\\xff]+';

        $quoted_pair = '\\x5c[\\x00-\\x7f]';

        $domain_literal = "\\x5b($dtext|$quoted_pair)*\\x5d";

        $quoted_string = "\\x22($qtext|$quoted_pair)*\\x22";

        $domain_ref = $atom;

        $sub_domain = "($domain_ref|$domain_literal)";

        $word = "($atom|$quoted_string)";

        $domain = "$sub_domain(\\x2e$sub_domain)*";

        $local_part = "$word(\\x2e$word)*";

        $addr_spec = "$local_part\\x40$domain";

        return preg_match("!^$addr_spec$!", $email) ? true : false;
    }
```